# If $f(x)$ is a cubic polynomial which has local maximum at $x=-1$. If $f(2)=18$, $f(1)=-1$ and $f’(x)$ has a local min at $x=0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, polynomials

> If $f(x)$ is a cubic polynomial which has local maximum at $x=-1$. If $f(2)=18$, $f(1)=-1$ and $f’(x)$ has a local min at $x=0$. Prove that $f(x)$ is increasing for $x\in [1,2\sqrt 5]$ and has a local minima at $x=1$

Let $f(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$

Here $$8a+4b+2c+d=18$$
And
$$f’(x)=3ax^2+2bx+c$$
$$\implies 3a-2b+c=0$$

Now $f’(x)$ has a minimum at $x=0$
$$f’’(x)=6ax+2b=0$$
$$b=0$$

So
$$3a+c=0$$
,$$8a+2c+d=18$$

And from $f(1)=-1$
$$a+c+d=-1$$

Solving  the equations
$$a=\frac{19}{4}$$
$$d=\frac{17}{2}$$
$$c=-\frac{57}{4}$$

But the function formed doesn’t satisfy the given requirements. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: $8a+2c+d$ should be $18$ not $0$.

Comment: $f(x) = \frac{19 x^3}{4}-\frac{57 x}{4}+\frac{17}{2}$ satisfies all the requirements and is increasing for $x\leq -1\lor x\geq 1$.

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of superfluous information given. You do not need to find $a,b,c,d,$ to answer the question.  But, the values that you have are fine.

Once you have $f'(x) = 3a^2 x^2 + c$, and $f'(-1) = 0$ you can can say $f'(1) = 0.$

If $f'(0)$  is a minimum of the derivative, the derivative is increasing through the point $f'(1)$ i.e. negative on the left side of 1 and positive on the right.

This is enough information to declare $f(1)$ is a minimum.  There are no other critical points.  So, there all the extrema have  been identified.  The function is increasing everywhere to the right of $1.$

You could also say that cubics either have one maximum and one minimum, or they are monotonic.  So, knowing that $f(-1)$ is a max, it must be that $f(1)$ is a min.

It is also the case cubics are symmetric about their point of inflection.  Or, the point of inflection lies half-way between the maximum and the minimum of a cubic.  Knowing the location of the max and the PI will give you the min without calculating a single derivative.